# Permissions issue trying to create an external data source on Azure SQL Database

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage, sql-grant

Please bear with me as I am trying to learn Azure. I have in my resource group a SQL Server database, and a blob storage account with a container. I am the owner of these resources.

I am trying to create an external data source on my SQL database to link to my blob storage account, but I am running into a permissions issue that I cannot seem to resolve. Running the query:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE MyAzureBlobStorage
WITH (
    TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE,
    LOCATION = 'https://[redacted].blob.core.windows.net/'
);
```

Returns this error message:

```
Msg 15247, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
User does not have permission to perform this action.
```

My Google-fu seems to be betraying me, as I can't seem to find any references to this issue. Am I missing something basic? I'm browsing through my Azure Dashboard but I can't find any obvious way to manage specific database permissions, although I would have assumed that given that I am the owner, I had maximum possible permissions?

Answer (score 1):

Please provide the credential as shown below:

```
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'some strong password';

CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL MyAzureBlobStorageCredential
 WITH IDENTITY = 'SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE',
 SECRET = 'sv=2015-12-11&ss=b&srt=sco&sp=rwac&se=2017-02-01T00:55:34Z&st=2016-12-29T16:55:34Z&spr=https&sig=copyFromAzurePortal';

CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE MyAzureBlobStorage
 WITH ( TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE,
        LOCATION = 'https://myazureblobstorage.blob.core.windows.net',
        CREDENTIAL= MyAzureBlobStorageCredential);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Running that script you provided (with the obvious modifications) yields the same error, on line 3.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same error when trying to create an `EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE`. What worked for me was add the grant `CONTROL` for the database user:

```
GRANT CONTROL to your_db_user
```